# MaxLength in input field not working on mobile phone but works on laptop

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, mobile

I have a couple of input fields and i am trying to restrict the number of characters a user can enter in those input fields.

For one particular input field, everything seems to work fine on my laptop but when I test it on my mobile phone, I can type characters exceeding the maximum length given.

The other input fields work fine on both mobile and desktop except this particular one.

This is my code for the input field that doesn't work on mobile:-

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="e.g. random placeholder" maxlength="24" oninput="function1(this);function2(this)" onkeydown="function3(this)">
```

This is the code for another of the input fields that work on both mobile and desktop:-

```
<input type="text" name="number" id="number" placeholder="e.g. random placeholder" maxlength="20" oninput="function1(this);function2(this)" onkeydown = "function3(this)">
```

It is important to note that it has nothing to do with the javaScript as they both have the same functions attached to it.